# Getting "AWS ACM CerError" when trying to deploy Cloudonaut Wordpress Cloudformation template

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When trying to deploy [Cloudonaut's](https://templates.cloudonaut.io/en/stable/wordpress/) WordPress Cloudformation [template](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/widdix-aws-cf-templates-releases-eu-west-1/stable/wordpress/wordpress-ha-aurora.yaml)(Step 5), I'm running into the following error.

`The certificate that is attached to your distribution doesn't cover the alternate domain name (CNAME) that you're trying to add. For more details, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-requirements (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate;`

I tried creating ACM certificates with domain.com, *.domain.com and also www.domain.com

But every time the stack fails with the same error.

Any guidance on how to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Sample stack info screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS9y3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The error basically tells this:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=6725

The cert may include domain.com, *.domain.com and also www.domain.com but does it match with the CNAME/Alias you're defining in the CloudFront parameter ?

Comment: Hmm.., I'm leaving the subdomain value as blank as described.
```SubDomainNameWithDot
Name that is used to create the DNS entry with trailing dot, e.g. ?{SubDomainNameWithDot}?{HostedZoneName}. Leave blank for naked (or apex and bare) domain.
```